# Campari or Aperol - the sweeter one?

Tags: taste, spirits, cocktails, alcohol-level, colour

Campari or Aperol - which is sweeter or maybe less bitter than the other one?

Comment: Hi san - welcome. Can you please edit your question to be a bit more focused - we really need it to be one question that needs a specific answer. Have you tasted either of them? They are very different.

Comment: Of course Rory, I've tasted Campari and its too bitter. I'd prefer 3 cap full of Campari with the rest of the glass with orange juice actually. But i only heard about Aperol and hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Campari](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campari) or [Aperol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperol) - the sweeter one?**

Aperol is clearly the sweeter of the two and maybe somewhat less bitter at the same time.

> [**Campari vs Aperol: what’s the difference?**](https://www.acouplecooks.com/campari-vs-aperol/)
>
> Campari and Aperol are Italian bitter liquors with several key differences. Here’s a breakdown:
>
> **Campari overview**
>
> **Origin:** Campari was invented in Italy in 1860 by Gaspare Campari in Novare, Italy. Because it’s got such a long history, it’s a featured ingredient in classic cocktails like the Negroni.
>
> **Colour**: Campari is bright red in color. Fun fact: The bright red color of Campari originally came from a dye made of crushed insects! That’s no longer in the modern recipe, so it shouldn’t deter you from grabbing a bottle.
>
> **Flavour**: Campari tastes very bitter, with sweet notes like cherry, clove, cinnamon and orange peel.
>
> **Alcohol content:** Campari is 48 proof or 24 percent ABV, almost twice that of Aperol.
>
> **Aperol overview**
>
> **Origin:** Aperol was also invented in Italy, but much later in 1919. Brothers Luigi and Silvio Barbieri created this aperitif in Padua, Italy. The company that sells Campari, Gruppo Campari, bought Aperol in the 1990s.
>
> **Colour**: Aperol is a bright orange color: it’s very distinct from Campari.
>
> **Flavour**: The flavor of Aperol is sweeter and more balanced than Campari, with notes of citrus and herbs.
>
> **Alcohol content:** Aperol has a lower alcohol content than Campari: it is 22 proof or 11 percent ABV.

Answer (score 3):

Aperol is much sweeter, in my opinion. My wife thinks both are too bitter for her.

YMMV